# Windows Boot Manager complains after I deleted Remix OS from Ubuntu/Windows/Remix triple boot

Tags: 16.04, windows-10

I was dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

I installed Remix OS (Android on desktop) so I could triple boot. Remix OS started boot-looping and I couldn't unistall it due to corrupted files so I just deleted it.

The next time I switched on my machine I got a screen from Windows Boot Manager saying Windows has been disabled to boot. To restore insert installation cd etc. I don't have an installation CD, so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I made one of my usb drives windows install disk (with windows media creation tool), booted up, installed, BUT i didn't install it on top of my windows, ubuntu and remix os, i deleted ALL partitions and let the windows roll. Later i reinistalled ubuntu, but left the remix os business.